# Axios get() call doesn't work on a working endpoint

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

I have a React app with the Facebook login functionality. To login, I need to hit the endpoint "http://localhost:5000/api/auth/facebook" with a GET request. This somehow works when I'm using a plain link:

```
<a href="http://localhost:5000/api/auth/facebook">Login</a>
```

It first calls the Facebook oAuth call, and then calls the callback endpoint to receive the token.

The same doesn't work with Axios.

This is **the React component part:** with the link and the prop function.

```
return (
      <div>
        <div>Dashboard</div>
        <a
          href="http://localhost:5000/api/auth/facebook"
          //onClick={this.LoginWithFacebook}
        >
          Login with Facebook Href
        </a>
        <button onClick={this.props.LoginWithFacebook}>
          Login with faceebook Func
        </button>
      </div>
    );
```

**The login function:**

```
export const LoginWithFacebook = () => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const result = await axios.get("api/auth/facebook");

    dispatch({
      type: LOGIN_USER,
      payload: result.data
    });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: GET_ERRORS,
      payload: err
    });
  }
};
```

With this function, it just hits the oAuth route, but doesn't hit the callback endpoint.

**[UPD]** The referer is set to http://localhost:3000/ when calling the endpoint from the function, and the status is `pending`. I have no idea why, since I've used the proxy in package.json, and other functions work well.

**[UPD2] Network screenshots**

**With link (works):**
[image]

**With function (doesn't work):**
[image]

```
fetch("https://www.facebook.com/v3.2/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5000%2Fapi%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&scope=public_profile%2Cemail&client_id=XXXXXXXXX", {"credentials":"omit","referrer":"http://localhost:3000/","referrerPolicy":"no-referrer-when-downgrade","body":null,"method":"GET","mode":"cors"});
```

**Note**, I have edited the `client_id`

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Your react app runs on port 3000 and your api on 5000 so maybe try `axios.get("/api/auth/facebook");` and [set a proxy](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) in your web config. If you publish your application I assume the static content (react app) and the api will run on the same server.

Comment: There is a proxy in my package.json, I mentioned: "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",

Comment: I missed that, sorry. But the url given to axios should still start with `/` assuming your api path is `/api/auth/facebook`

Comment: Thanks, I fixed, but still didn't work. I will update the post now with Network screenshots.

Comment: if you see the request in network tab (devtools) you can right click it => copy => copy as fetch. Maybe add code generated to the question.

Comment: Added the request and the screenshots.

Comment: I've also checked the 'copy as fetch' for the working URL, and there are credentials that are included. I passed "withCredentials: true" to axios, but still didn't work :/

Comment: I don't think you can do this with a ajax request because with oath the user needs to actually go to the facebook site to log in and then facebook will direct the user back to your site after login.